# Can someone explain join method in Java Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
    public final synchronized void join(long millis) throwsInterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

How does wait(0) make the main thread wait until it finishes. Thread is calling wait on itself? As far as my understanding it must have a lock on itself to call wait() method? How does it notify the main thread when it finishes?

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) explains the logic:

> This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

So this implementation relies on the fact that the `Thread` object does not just represent a thread, but is also an object like any other object in Java. As such, it inherits from `Object`, has its own monitor and can be synchronized, have threads `wait`ing on it, etc.

> It must have a lock on itself to call `wait()` method?

Yes. And indeed, this method is declared **`synchronized`**. So it synchronizes on the Thread instance itself. Once you are inside it, you have the `Thread` instance's monitor. Then when `wait` is called, you relinquish it, so other threads can do the same thing.

This might be a bit confusing. Your currently running thread is thread A. You are using `join` on thread B. The object being synchronized on here is the instance of thread B, and this causes thread A to wait until `notifyAll` is called on the same (B) instance.

When the thread B finishes, it calls `notifyAll` on its own instance. So any threads that are blocked in a `wait` on thread B's instance will be notified.

Comment: That is indeed confusing...
another question:
```while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }```
what's the benefit of calling wait() here? it's also ok just busy-waiting inside the while loop without wait(0), maybe? and who is the one notify the thead A?

Comment: Busy waiting is never ok. And the one notifying thread A is thread B, when it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as my understanding it must have lock on itself to call wait() method?

Not on *itself*, but on the `Thread` object.  And the caller *does* have a lock on the `Thread` object.  Notice that `t.join()` is a `synchronized` method.

> How does it notifies to the main thread when it finishes?

Don't get confused by the difference between a `Thread` and a *thread*.  A `Thread` instance is a heap object that a program uses to start and manage the life-cycle of a thread of execution in the code.  It's methods often are called by *other* threads than the one it is managing.

If thread A calls `t.join()`, it will lock the object `t`, and then it will call `t.wait()` as many times as it takes until the state of `t` is `Thread.State.TERMINATED`.

Remember that, inside each `t.wait()` call, the lock is released, and then re-acquired before the wait() returns.

In the thread that is managed by `t`, one of the very last things that it does is, it sets the state of `t` to `TERMINATED`, and then calls `t.notify()`.  That will wake up thread A.

Answer (score 0):

obj.wait() causes current thread to sleep, until some another thread call obj.notify() .

t.join() - causes current thread to wait until thread 't' finishes